# Downloading file from FTP server with ftplib: Always 0 bytes/empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to download a file from an FTPS server, using Python ftplib.

But the downloaded file has always 0 bytes (is empty).
If I see the file in the server with WinSCP, the file has data (about 1Kb).
In WinSCP I'm using the options *"Encryption: Explicit TSL"* and *"PassiveMode=False"*.

What is wrong with the code?
Thanks!!

This is the code I am using:

```
import ftplib

server='10.XX.XX.XX'
username='username'
password='password'

session = ftplib.FTP_TLS(server)
session.login(user=username,passwd=password)
session.prot_p()
session.set_pasv(False)
session.nlst()
session.cwd("home")
print(session.pwd())
filename = "test.txt"
# Open a local file to store the downloaded file
my_file = open(r'c:\temp\ftpTest.txt', 'wb') 
session.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, my_file.write, 1024)

session.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not closing the local file after the download. You should use context manager for that. Similarly also for the FTP session:

```
with ftplib.FTP_TLS(server) as session:
    session.login(user=username, passwd=password)
    session.prot_p()
    session.set_pasv(False)
    session.nlst()
    session.cwd("home")
    print(session.pwd())
    filename = "test.txt"
    # Open a local file to store the downloaded file
    with open(r'c:\temp\ftpTest.txt', 'wb') as my_file: 
        session.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, my_file.write, 1024)
```